# a:hover somehow not working

Tags: css

I'm working on this page http://seriesaddict.fr/Hunted/772 and I have this:

```
.ficheserie_casting img.style_img, img.style_img a:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
.ficheserie_casting img.style_img, img.style_img a {opacity: 1;}
```

the hover doesn't work, anyone can tell me why ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to hover on the `img` element, but you're assigning the hover to an `a` tag which is apparently within an `img` tag, which is not correct HTML:

Incorrect:

```
<img><a></a></img>
```

Correct:

```
<a><img /></a>
```

Change your css to:

```
.ficheserie_casting img.style_img, img.style_img:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
.ficheserie_casting img.style_img, img.style_img {opacity: 1;}
```